# Auto focus on different images

Tags: image, image-processing, camera, mathematical-morphology

I have some images of a fluidic system taken from a camera at different focuses.

How can i decide in which focus I have the best images?
Which features of image do i have to look at?
Is there a measurement of sharpness on different images?

[Example image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHwqe.png)

[image]

[Example image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDi2v.png)

[image]

**Every image is different from each other.**

Thanks.

Comment: The total variation is larger for a sharp image. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation

Comment: Hi.
The best images i can take are most sharpened images. So i used max variance to find max sharpened image. It worked. Thanks to @Yves Daoust

Comment: Total variation is not the variance ! Sharpness has very little impact on the variance.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact your examples demonstrate clear difference between "good" and "bad" quality images you can use a simple edge detection filter to make the difference obvious.

This approach literally highlights depth of field (DOF):

[image]
([see in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Rr0vfGBCAY&t=31s))

Let's apply to your examples:

**example 1**

[image]

**example 2**

[image]

Even a simple thresholding technique will provide a proper result.